# SPI Clock Frequency changes when level shifted

Tags: spi, level-shifting

I'm using Adafruit's TXB0108 bi-directional 8 channel level shifter with my Arduino Uno. The SPI clock from Pin 13 is level-shifted through the first channel of the level shifter. Measured with my multimeter, the frequency of Pin 13 is 3.439Mhz. However the measurement of the output of the level shifter is 245 (+/- 10) Khz. And I have no idea why! I checked the [datasheet](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/txb0108.pdf) of the level shifter, and I think it should be good to 10 Mhz.

Running the following code the following:

```
#include <SPI.h> 
void setup()
{
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  SPI.begin();
  SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV2);    

}
void loop()
{

  byte pot = B0;                
  SPI.transfer(pot);                        //  Do SPI transfer of variable pot
}
```

Comment: Have you observed the waveforms on an oscilloscope?  Maybe your meter is measuring the frequency of the 8-bit blocks of data instead of the clock frequency within them?

Comment: No I haven't tried with an oscilloscope. 8 bit block measurement does not make sense. If so, shouldn't both measurements be the same frequency anyways?

Comment: It depends on how your meter deals with it at the different voltages - and the waves may be a different shape after shifting.  Get a scope on it and don't rely on just a number on your meter. See the waves for yourself.

Comment: Ah that makes a lot more sense. I'm getting a saleae logic analyzer once and for all. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the frequency measurement on a scope.  It is probable that the waveform coming out of the level shifter is being misinterpreted by the meter.  It is possible that this is just due to the different voltage, but it could also be distorted or rounded off.  And a saelae logic analyzer may not provide enough information if the signal is distorted in some way, you will likely need an actual DSO with a decent analog bandwidth (bandwidth of 1/2 clock frequency is the absolute minimum required to get the state (1 vs 0) but not the shape, bandwidth of 10x clock frequency will give you a very good idea about the shape).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Can you recommend a DSO? Saleae's Logic 8 took little convincing. $200 is not much, but I understand DSO are much more expansive =(.

Comment: Rigol makes some decent scopes; it's pretty hard to beat the four-channel DS1054Z (50 MHz, $400) / DS1104Z (100 MHz, $800) in value.

Comment: Also, I would suggest getting a DS1054Z instead of a DS1104Z, and then taking a look at the EEVblog forums.  They have some interesting information on those units.  Actually, take a look at the forum first - there are discount codes for tequipment that can apply to the scope.